# Calculate effective rate of the loan - additional fees

Tags: finance

I am having following parameters:

```
loan_value = 20000
Annual rate = 2.9%
other fees = 500
periods of repayment = 24 (2 years, each month)
additional fees per month = 2
```

now, given the formula:

`EIR = loan_value * (1+Annual rate/24) power (periods of repayment)` I get EIR of 2.94%, where did my bank get 5.78% ??? I would really appreciate the explanation.

Comment: It is obvious that your formula cannot work due the fees you pay.

Comment: Why `Annual rate/24` rather than divide by the number of months in a year?  And If EIR is in a sense annual, why not raise to the power of $12$?

Comment: @callculus42 O.K., but how to include fees if may I ask? I calculated how much I pay at the end and divided that with (loan_payment - fees) and I still didn't get the 5,578%

Comment: @Henry but then EIR would be even lower, I want to know how my bank got 5.78%

Comment: @filtertips It is much more difficult. Maybe the calculation can be comprehended by using an excel sheet.